# Why does `rake db:seed` fail with "Don't know how to build task 'db:seed:original'"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

When I try to seed my Rails 4.0 app, I get this error:

```
$ rake db:seed --trace
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Invoke db:seed:common (first_time)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:seed:original'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:57:in `lookup_prerequisite'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:53:in `block in prerequisite_tasks'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:53:in `map'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:53:in `prerequisite_tasks'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed => db:seed:common
```

But I can't find any references to a seed task called `original`. Is this something built in to Rails?

If I call any of my seed tasks manually by e.g. `rake db:seed:whatever`, it works fine.

Amusingly, after I created a **empty** file called `original.seeds.rb` in my seeds folder, the seeding ran without error.

What caused this error?

Comment: Do you have db/seeds.rb ?

Comment: Nope. When I created an empty one (and deleted `original.seeds.rb`), it worked. Any idea why Rake expects a file there?

Comment: @neo I assume that was the cause of the problem. If you'd like to expand that into an answer (especially if you know why that file was expected), I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a dummy `db/seeds.rb` to solve this. when you run `rake db:seed` it expects you to have that file.